# In materialui, for setting margin, is there a way to use theme.spacing and auto together?

Tags: material-ui

In materialui, for setting a margin, is there a way to use theme.spacing() and auto together?

Something like margin: theme.spacing(1) auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer; the technique is:
margin: theme.spacing(5, 'auto'),